# Iterate thru different worksheets and prevent the loop from exiting

Tags: python, for-loop, google-sheets, gspread

This might be a brain wrecking to explain but I'll try
So there's a google sheet that I want to modify using python using [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/index.html)
Different rooms is placed in worksheet with the same format.
Here's a image for reference
[image]

Code Follows:

```
room_list = sh.worksheets()
room = []
b = 0
for randioom in room_list:
    temp = str(room_list[b])
    print (temp)
    temp_room_list = re.findall(r"'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)", temp)
    room.append(temp_room_list[0])
b+=1
print (room)
c = 0
d = 1
wks1 = sh.worksheet("List of Applicants")
for randission in splitted_email:
    result = wks1.row_values(wks1.find(str(splitted_email[c][0])).row)
    c+=1
    wks2 = sh.worksheet(str(room[d]))
    x = 0
    y = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    row = 0
    try:
        col = str((len(wks2.col_values("2"))) + 1)
        for details in range (0, 4, +1):
            wks2.update(str(y[row] + col), result[x])
            x+=1
            row+=1
            b+=1
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError as full:
        print("Room is full, Going to another room")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Scanning Rooms")
        
        d+=1
        wks2 = sh.worksheet(str(room[d]))
        col = str((len(wks2.col_values("2"))) + 1)
        for details in range (0, 4, +1):
            wks2.update(str(y[row] + col), result[x])
            x+=1
            row+=1
            b+=1
    continue
```

In this code it checks a email if it exists in the `List of Applicants` worksheet then writing the email details in the `RM 202 8AM` worksheet if it exists. It loops until the worksheet is full and then finally outputting a error which is `gspread.exceptions.APIError` which translates to worksheet is full.

What I did to loop it around thru worksheet is to check different worksheet that will not output a exception and while doing that I increment the variable `d` which is the key to select specific index in `results` which contains a list of worksheets and if the error doesn't exists it will print it there . 
But this is where the problem began.

It only checks 2 worksheets which is `RM 202 8AM` and `RM 202 10AM`. I want it to loop thru all worksheet and check where is the worksheet that isn't full or have space to place the email details

If my explanation is still not understandable, Please don't hesitate to point it out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit, I realized that I can use while loop to make it happen.
Code follows:

```
try:
    col = str((len(wks2.col_values("2"))) + 1)
    for details in range (0, 4, +1):
        wks2.update(str(y[row] + col), result[x])
        x+=1
        row+=1
        b+=1
except gspread.exceptions.APIError:
    print("Room is full, Going to another room")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Scanning Rooms")
    while True:
        try:
            d+=1
            wks2 = sh.worksheet(str(room[d]))
            col = str((len(wks2.col_values("2"))) + 1)
            for details in range (0, 4, +1):
                wks2.update(str(y[row] + col), result[x])
                x+=1
                row+=1
                b+=1
            break
        except gspread.exceptions.APIError:
            print(room[d], "is full, changing room")
        except IndexError:
            print("All Worksheet is full, please add more Room Worksheets")      
    continue
```

Now it works like catch and do process.
Every time that it catches the gspread exception it will print out the specific room that is full and then with while loop, it will automatically try and find a  again until it succeded to find a worksheet that isn't full hence breaking the while loop after wards.

With that it will `continue` again in the first for loop